# How to return sum of LocalTime in Java

Tags: java, time, localtime

It wont get the minutes. i need to return minutes.
How to return sum of minutes while iterating over Localtime in Java?

```
public String userLunchHoursSum(String username) {
    List<WorkHour> workHours = workHourRepository.findWorkHoursByUsername(username);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(workHours.toArray()));
    long diff = 0;
    LocalTime lunchTime;
    long minutes = 0;
    LocalTime plusMinutes = null;
    for (WorkHour workHour : workHours) {
        lunchTime = workHour.getLunch_time().toLocalTime(); //00:30:00
        plusMinutes = lunchTime.plusMinutes(lunchTime.getMinute());
    }
    if(workHours.size()!= 0) {
        return Long.toString(plusMinutes.getMinute());
    }
    return "00:00";
}
```

`getLunch_time` returns `java.sql.Time`.

Comment: There are only sixty minutes in an hour. I'm pretty sure you wanted [a `Duration` or a `Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html). Basically, a `LocalTime` is for an instant in time. Not a duration or a period.

Comment: How it should be looked like?

Comment: It depends on the result you expect. Click on the link I already provided. It's to the Java Tutorials, and should answer your questions.

Comment: What should i use then?

Comment: It appears to me that you would like the total time someone was at lunch. That sounds like a `Duration` to me. I hate to keep repeating this but you really should read the link I provided.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you should be storing duration instead of localtime. If this is something you have no control over, consider migrating the database or creating a intermediate parsing function. Example code that I have not run, because I don't know what is in `WorkHour`.

```
// leave the string formatting to other functions
public long userLunchHoursSum(String username) {
    List<WorkHour> workHours = workHourRepository.findWorkHoursByUsername(username);
    Duration totalDuration = Duration.ZERO;
    for (WorkHour workHour : workHours) {
        // save your time in the appropriate format beforehand
        // do not use local time to store duration.
        Duration lunchTime = Duration.between(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT, workHour.getLunch_time().toLocalTime()); //00:30:00
        totalDuration = totalDuration.plus(lunchTime);
    }
    return totalDuration.toMinutes();
}
```

Comment: getLunch_time is java.sql.Time;

Comment: plusMinutes()requires long but provided Duration

Comment: @anduplats please accept the answer if it solves your question.

Comment: It’s not solving the OP’s basic problem of using the wrong types and further complicating things by mixing outdated and modern classes. Assuming that the OP cannot change the types used by the `WorkHour` class (the poorly designed and long outdated `java.sql.Time`), this is about the best we can do, so in this sense it’s a good answer.